# how to make these simple functions tail recursive in f#

Tags: list, recursion, f#, tail-recursion

I have these these two functions

```
//Remove all even indexed elements from a list and return the rest
let rec removeEven l =
match l with
| x0::x1::xs -> x1::removeEven (xs)
| [] -> []
| [_] -> []

//combine list members into pairs
let rec combinePair l =
match l with
| x0::x1::xs -> (x0,x1) :: combinePair(xs)
| [] -> []
| [_] -> []
```

That work.

But I thought now that I was at it that I might as well learn a bit about tail recursion which I'm having a hard time getting the grasp of.

That's why I thought that if I could get some help making functions I had made myself tail-recursive perhaps it would become more clear how it works, instead of reading an example somewhere which I might not understand as well as my own code (remember, I'm a complete f# newbie :))

Any other constructive comments about my code are of course most welcome!

Comment: I think it is correct.
It is supposed to remove the even-indexed, not the even-valued elements and in this case 1 has index 0 and 2 has index 1

Comment: Why does `removeEven [1;2]` return `[2]`? I copied its behavior in my answer, but it seems it should be called `returnEven` or `removeOdd` or something.

Comment: Sorry to delete my comment. I rephrased it. So _even_ refers to the index? Okay.

Comment: @Daniel : The comment at the top of the code has said that all along. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: Who reads code comments?!? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical way of making functions tail-recursive in F# is using a list (`acc` in this case) to accumulate results and reversing it to get the correct order:

```
let removeEven l =
    let rec loop xs acc =
        match xs with        
        | [] | [_] -> acc
        | _::x1::xs' -> loop xs' (x1::acc)
    loop l [] |> List.rev

let combinePair l =
    let rec loop xs acc =
        match xs with        
        | [] | [_] -> acc
        | x0::x1::xs' -> loop xs' ((x0, x1)::acc)
    loop l [] |> List.rev
```

Since we simply return results after each recursive call of `loop`, these functions are tail-recursive.

Your functions look quite nice, but I still have several comments:

- Indentation is important in F#. I would prefer `match... with` is a few spaces behind `lec rec` declaration.
- Patter matching cases should follow a consistent order. It's a good idea to start with base cases first.
- The `function` keyword is natural to use for shortening functions whenever you have a pattern of `fun t -> match t with`.
- It's better to get rid of unnecessary parentheses, especially in functions with one argument.

Applying above comments, your functions become as follows:

```
// Remove all even indexed elements from a list and return the rest
let rec removeEven = function
    | [] | [_] -> []
    | _::x1::xs -> x1::removeEven xs

// Combine list members into pairs
let rec combinePair = function
    | [] | [_] -> []
    | x0::x1::xs -> (x0, x1)::combinePair xs
```

Comment: Really nice! thx a lot that's excactly what I was looking for.
Not completely sure I understand what the "loop l [] |> List.rev"
line does. I mean I know it is supposed to reverse the list but why the loop l []? and when will that rec code be reached?

Comment: `| [] -> [] | [_] -> []` could also be collapsed into `| [] | [_] -> []`, saving two lines.

Comment: @ildjarn: Your suggestion has been applied :).

Comment: @PNS: That line is the same as `List.rev (loop l [])`. We start accumulating from an empty list. When the input list has less than 2 elements, we return the accumulator list and reverse it.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a slower, less maintainable way to do it that uses more memory, you can use a continuation.

```
let removeEven items = 
  let rec loop f = function
    | _::h::t -> loop (fun acc -> f (h::acc)) t
    | [] | [_] -> f []
  loop id items
```

But hey, it's tail-recursive.

Comment: I think the result needs to be reversed

Comment: @TysonWilliams No, sir. It does not.

Comment: Oh, yes.  Your are correct.  Sorry for my mistake.  (I knew I should have tested it before making that comment :P )